# GeoFire structure doesn't match documentation

Tags: jquery, firebase, rsvp.js, geofire

GeoFire is saving data using an undocumented structure. How can I get it to save like the official examples. I haven't followed any particular tutorial or guide, but I've based my work heavily on these examples.

I've been able to replicate the issue:

JS:

```
var ref = new Firebase("https://skgz3dfvs9.firebaseio-demo.com");
var geoFire = new GeoFire(ref.child("_geofire"));

geoFire.set("ADb3b3j2"+parseInt(Math.random(1000)*10000), [20.573771400000002, -100.35827]).then(function() {
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Provided key has been added to GeoFire";
}, function(error) {
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Error: " + error;
});
```

HTML

```
<div id="result"></div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/johnhparkerg/c0852c6s/1/

Results in a JSON that looks like this:

```
{  
   "_geofire":{  
      "i":{  
         "9g8th336fu:ADb3b3j2":true,
         "9g8th336fu:ADb3b3j21770":true,
         "9g8th336fu:ADb3b3j23390":true,
         "9g8th336fu:ADb3b3j24122":true,
         "9g8th336fu:ADb3b3j25036":true,
         "9g8th336fu:ADb3b3j27393":true,
         "9g8th336fu:ADb3b3j28182":true,
         "9g8th336fu:ADb3b3j28276":true,
         "9g8th336fu:ADb3b3j29206":true,
         "9g8th336fu:ADb3b3j29674":true
      },
      "l":{  
         "ADb3b3j2":[  
            20.573771400000002,
            -100.35827
         ],
         "ADb3b3j21770":[  
            20.573771400000002,
            -100.35827
         ],
         "ADb3b3j23390":[  
            20.573771400000002,
            -100.35827
         ],
         "ADb3b3j24122":[  
            20.573771400000002,
            -100.35827
         ],
         "ADb3b3j25036":[  
            20.573771400000002,
            -100.35827
         ],
         "ADb3b3j27393":[  
            20.573771400000002,
            -100.35827
         ],
         "ADb3b3j28182":[  
            20.573771400000002,
            -100.35827
         ],
         "ADb3b3j28276":[  
            20.573771400000002,
            -100.35827
         ],
         "ADb3b3j29206":[  
            20.573771400000002,
            -100.35827
         ],
         "ADb3b3j29674":[  
            20.573771400000002,
            -100.35827
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

https://skgz3dfvs9.firebaseio-demo.com/

When the result should look like this:

```
{  
   "fish1":{  
      "g":"pns0h0mf2u",
      "l":[  
         -53.435719,
         140.808716
      ]
   },
   "fish2":{  
      "g":"u417k3dwub",
      "l":[  
         56.83069,
         1.94822
      ]
   },
   "fish3":{  
      "g":"8m3rz3s480",
      "l":[  
         30.902225,
         -166.66809
      ]
   }
}
```

(This structure is pervasive across examples and documentation regarding firebase and geofire)

Here are the [examples](https://geofire.firebaseapp.com/).

I hope I was clear enough, otherwise let me know.

Comment: instead of linking to a dashboard, include the (minimal) JSON into your question (as text). Links rot, as the image in the question you linked to shows. Your jsfiddle is empty btw.

Comment: Aside from that, I don't understand what you're asking. Why is the structure wrong according to you? How did you write the structure? The fact that it is different from a tutorial is irrelevant, unless you're trying to follow that tutorial. But if that is the case, show the exact minimal code that you used. Without an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) it's difficult to help.

Comment: I've edited to make it clearer, please be so kind as to give me your opinion about the clarity of the question and if it is possible, some guidance.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that an earlier version of GeoFire stored data in a different format, problem was that there was no reference to that... anywhere.